# Django-select2: ModelSelect2MultipleWidget doesn't show any options

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use `ModelSelect2MultipleWidget` on `User` model.

```
class NFForm(Form):
    user = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all(),widget=ModelSelect2MultipleWidget(model=User))
```

The problem is that the `select` says:

> No results found

[image]

On the other hand, if I use `Select2MultipleWidget`, it works correctly and it shows all users as options.

The problem is that I want to customize options so I need to use `ModelSelect2MultipleWidget` and override it's `label_from_instance` method.

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the console says ajax not found. And u need the non-slim version of jQuery from [here](https://jquery.com/%20download/#jquery).